# Why doesn't Distinct with Entity Framework do "DISTINCT" on SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, distinct

I just recently switched out our repository and context from Linq-to-SQL to Entity Framework 4.1 CodeFirst.

All my unit tests are passing at the moment, except one! And that is the one that checks if I get a distinct result from a SQL-view.

```
var query = worker.ObjectRepository.GetFreeObjects();
query = query.Distinct();
return query;
```

When I inspect the query just before I call .Distinct(), the query is correct and it runs fine when I execute it manually on SQL Server.

But after I call `.Distinct()`, the query just looks the exact same as before.

If I manually add a DISTINCT to my SQL query, it works fine, but calling `.Distinct()` in code doesn't do this.

Why is that?

**Edit**

```
public IQueryable<SearchResultValueObject> GetFreeObjects()
{
    return Get(Context.FreeObjects)
}

public IQueryable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query)
{
    return query;
}
```

I simplyfied a bit becaus at this scenario that's all that is happening. Grabbing the data from the Context, and returning it.

This is how my Context look

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<SearchResultValueObject> SearchResult { get; set; }

    IQueryable<SearchResultValueObject> IMyContext.FreeObjects { get { return this.SearchResult; } }
}
```

I also tried to remove everything except the objectNo from the SearchResultMap-file, I got the results from the Db, but `.Distinct()` didn't work.

**Edit2**

I made a simple example that has the same problem: http://pastebin.com/sYVfNb0Y
Does this has something to do with the fact that I'm fetching from a view? Or am I missing something important here?

Best regards
Jesper

Comment: You'll need to show the code for worker.ObjectRepository.GetFreeObjects().

Comment: For the linked example code @adrift's answer applies: You query for the full entity (no projection) therefore the primary key is one of the columns. In this case using `DISTINCT` or not would give the same result. Obviously EF recognizes this and omits the `DISTINCT` altogether.

Comment: But when I take the query EF generates, and run it in the SQL Management Studio with the added DISTINCT, it will return distinct rows. Is there any solution to get the desired effect?

Comment: Are the distinct rows different from the rows without using DISTINCT? That would be a bug imo. Can you show the SQL in your question which EF creates? Does it contain a primary key?

Comment: I'm selecting from a view, and in my map I defined HasKey(t => t.ObjectNo). ObjectNo isn't unique in the view, but SELECT DISTINCT objectNo AS ObjectNo from msvi_ObjectSearchList_Static returns unique objectNo's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love it if someone could find a way around this. But after several hours of looking around it all came down to me **making a new view based on the old view**.

I don't know if it's the right way to do it, but it helped me with my problem.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that your query includes a column that is guaranteed to be distinct and EF knows it doesn't need to include `DISTINCT` in the generated SQL.

I tested this using LINQPad and EF 4.1.  The model I tested against is a DB first model - I don't think that would matter, but figured I should mention it.

When the query includes the PK column, EF generates the same SQL when `.Distinct()` is called.

When I change the query to select only a non-PK column, I see `DISTINCT` appear in the SQL when `.Distinct()` is called.

Comment: Hmm, I know for a fact that I don't get distinct results. Could I have made some misstake when setting up the Map-object? I'm really green on EF and Code-First, so that's a big possibility. I'm trying to map a view, what should I use as keys then?

Comment: @HerrLiljegren can you update your question to include your setup code, and/or the code for `worker.ObjectRepository.GetFreeObjects()` as mentioned in the comments?